# Entity framework Data sorting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a project for UserStream(like fb) using entity framework, i have implemented it successfully, I want the functionality that if someone comment on a status/post that status/post should be shown on top,(like in FB)
For now the latest post is showing on top but i am unable to sort on the base of comments,below is my DB tables structure

```
tblPosts:                 tblUsers                     tblUserPosts:          tblPostComments
PostId bigint PK          UserId bigint PK             UserPostID bigint PK   CommentID bigint PK
Desc  text                Username  varchar(200)       UserID   bigint FK     PostId bigint FK
Type bingint              Password varchar(100)        PostId   bigint FK     Comment varchar(200)
URL  varchar(200)                                                             Commentedby bigint FK
Privacy varchar(50)                                                           Postedon datetime
Postedon datetime
```

On my cs code i am retrieving List of tblUserPosts then sorting it on the base of tblPosts Posteddate,but i am not having any information regarding tblPostComments, how can i sort records on the base of Comments as well

This is how i am sorting records

```
List<tblUserPosts> objlst = new List<tblUserPosts>();
//Adding items to objlst
      UserStreamViewModel model = new UserStreamViewModel
                {
//I am not having d.tblPostComments or d.tblPosts.tblComments.PostedOn
                    propResourcesList = objlst.OrderBy(d=>d.tblPosts.PostedOn);

                };
```

Comment: can you post some code on how you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: _I am not having any information regarding tblPostComments_. So how would you get the information you need? Have you got a DbContext of sorts? Can't you add a DbSet `tblPostComments` to the context? This question lacks some vital background information.